# Boss not giving raise because job helps side hustle

Tags: raise

I have a job in an entertainment related industry that I've been working at for 7 years. In that time I have gotten only small cost of living raises even though I've been taking on more responsibility and some coworkers who were there a shorter time make more. This job brings in a lot of income for a side hustle of mine as it helps me to acquire customers and I suspect my boss is using this as an excuse to not give me raises.

What should I do in this situation.  I'm kind of stuck working here because of the extra income that it gives me but I'm pissed that I'm not getting a raise and I can't quit because of the side hustle extra money, and my boss doesn't want to give me a raise. It's not fair that just because I'm making money from a side hustle I'm not getting a raise comparable to coworkers.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: There's always this question: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid) - but actually: your boss has no reason to care for your side business, as long as you do your first/main job

Comment: Have you been able (or is there a reasonable expectation based on specific numbers) to find another job that would earn you as much money as the old job + side hustle?

Comment: You have a distinct conflict of interest at play here. Depending on the locality, you can be fired, sued, and possibly prosecuted. You're concerned that your conflict of interest is being used as a foil to prevent paying you more? I don't know your locale, so I'm not going to say any of this is unethical, but it sure looks like it from how the question is presented.

Comment: "I suspect my boss is using this as an excuse to not give me raises" - Has this actually been said? The word "suspect" concerns me here.

Answer (score 10):

Personally it doesn't sound unfair to me. It's supply and demand at the end of the day, right. If you like what you are getting overall (including the side hustle) and don't want to change jobs, then it means you are getting a fair deal.

Maybe get some offers from other companies and see how you feel about the total package. If you don't find any overall better package, I wouldn't stress.

Comment: Actually this question is not for me Im asking for a youtuber from justkiddingnews but thnx anyways.

Answer (score 2):

An employer is never forced to give you more in a raise than what the law says. The reason for giving more in a raise is to have a better chance of keeping the employee for a longer period. Here is your problem that if you loose a lot on the side hustle because of the extra your normal work gives so you the employer does not have to be afraid of losing you then why would the raise be more than minimal allowed.

To be fair by working there the company helps your side hustle and it doesn't seem like you weigh that in much when it comes to appreciation.

You say you don't get comparable raises as to coworkers but you do get the benefit of getting contacts for your side hustle and that is something they don't get.

So as long as the combination of salary + gains to side hustle is better than what you get by changing company I would say you are paid market value in combination cash + contacts